# Connecting to php mail sever without php-library

Tags: php, email

How to connect a php testing server like https://mailtrap.io/ .
If i have defined variables like

```
$host = 'mail.sample.com';
$port=25;
$user="username";
$pass="secret";
```

maybe also $Auth = "PLAIN, LOGIN and CRAM-MD5" $TLS="Optional (STARTTLS on all ports)";
How to use these variables, nowhere i can find samples.
I want to use simple php mail function.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mailtrap is a fake SMTP server. However, the built-in PHP `mail()` function is simple and lacks SMTP authentication support — which is required by mailtrap.

So, move on an and use a PHP mailer package like PHPMailer, Swift Mailer, PearMail, etc as shown here https://blog.mailtrap.io/php-email-sending/

E.g. with PHPMailer

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// configure an SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '1a2b3c4d5e6f7g';
$mail->Password = '1a2b3c4d5e6f7g’;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 2525;

$mail->setFrom('confirmation@hotel.com', 'Your Hotel');
$mail->addAddress('me@gmail.com', 'Me');
$mail->Subject = 'Thanks for choosing Our Hotel!';
$mail->isHTML(TRUE);
$mail->Body = '<html>Hi there, we are happy to <br>confirm your booking.</br> Please check the document in the attachment.</html>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Hi there, we are happy to confirm your booking. Please check the document in the attachment.';

if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

There are other, haphazard options but I bet they are not working in your case. One of them is changing [mail directives in php.ini and sendmail.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#118210) (if you have access to it and feel adventurous).